# port 5432 is already in use windows?

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

hi guys I m trying to use postgreSql and when trying to open pgadmin 4 is not working and if i try fixing the port too the default 5432 it is said that is already in use .I found some solution but most of them work only on mac not windows .so if any one has a solution please help me

Answer (score 3):

You can change your port from 5432 to something like 5433, 5050 or 6543, to change follow the steps.

Step 1: Go to this PC -> OS(C:) -> Program Files -> PostgreSQL -> 14 -> data -
postgresql.conf.

Step 2: Right click on postgresql.conf  open in Edit with Notepad++ or vscode.

Step 3:  Go to the line number 64(might be in your notepad it will different) now change the port number 5432 to 5433 and save it and click on red cross to close.

Step 4: Window + R/(Run) -> 'service.msc' click ok.

Step 5: Search postgresql-x64-14(depending on your version) -> Right click and restart.

Step 6: Goto PgAdmin -> Right click on PostgreSQL14 and open properties -> Click on Connection -> change port 5432 to 5433 and click save.

Step 7: Right click on PostgreSQL14 and click Connect Server give password now ready to use.

Answer (score 2):

Your postgresql server is probably already occupying that port, or maybe some other program is. Try finding the program that uses the port using `netstat -aon | findstr '5432'` and terminate it, or change the postgresql config to use a different port instead.

Answer (score 1):

it worked when I run pgadmin4.exe as an admistrator. without ending that task .it workes fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Windows Start menu

Scroll down to postgreSql 14 and click

run pgAdmin 4 as an administrator.

If prompted for a password, enter the password you specified when installing postgresql.